# How can I use a space in a Qt application name?

Tags: macos, qt

The application name usually is defined by the

```
TARGET = MyApplication
```

statement in the MyApplication.pro file. My question is, how can I add a space to application name. Obviously the simple solution

```
TARGET = My Application
```

does not work. I am mainly interested in the application name as it is shown in the Mac OS X menu bar.

I am using Qt 4.7.4 with Qt Creator 2.4.1 on Mac OS 10.7.

I tried some solution from the internet like

http://grovr.blogspot.de/2010/11/putting-spaces-in-name-of-qt-for.html
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?207662-App-name-with-whitespace

but they didn't work.

Because I am new to Qt and also to Stack Overflow please apologize my mistakes.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Didn't work isn't very specific... What happened? An error? Two executables being created?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At least in Windows (Qt 4.8.0, Qt Creator 2.4.1) this works:

```
TARGET = "My Application"
```

Comment: Doesn't work with VS2010 compiler on Windows with qt5